# Pass special values through other params in oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

Dear Sir,
I need to pass some special characters through the url. The sample url will look like below

http:///forms/frmservlet?config=portal&pv_app_user_name=&pv_flg=Y&pv_app_code=&pv_passwd=¹¨§¸¯žf&pv_emailid=&PV_PFLG=Y

Can you please have a look on the pv_passwd section.Here i am passing some special characters for my application authentication.
Here my problem is, if i pass this value(¹¨§¸¯žf) , its appearing differently in the forms parameter. if we display the parameter value, its showing some different characters.

Is there any setting we need to do it in the configuration section. can you please help on the above query?

Regards
Mathew

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
http:///localhost:port/frmservlet?config=portal&otherparams=param1=firstparamvaluehere
```

It is a non typical url syntax because of 'otherparams=param1=....' construction but it works perfectly. Then you need to configure the receiving form to assing the url parameter to a form parameter to be accesible like this:

> **:parameter.param1**

If you need to pass more than one parameter concatenate with a plus "+" sign. For example:

```
http:///localhost:port/frmservlet?config=portal&otherparams=param1=firstparamvaluehere+param2=secondparamvaluehere+param3=....
```

Answer (score 0):

(*I would have made this a comment as it isn't really an answer, but a suggestion - not enough rep to comment!*)

I ran a quick test, and was able to display this string from a parameter with no change to its value.

Without any other information 
I would check the registry (Windows)

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Oracle/*ORACLE_HOME*** (*ORACLE_HOME* will be different on different systems - usually you want the one that refers to your development suite or Forms server installation)

key for a parameter called **NLS_LANG**.

On *nix this is an environment variable - **NLS_LANG**.

Mine is set to **AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252**.  You would have different results if yours is set differently, as it will use different character encoding.

Go character sets!